# Get a sentence encoding from word encoding using LSTM using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a word encoding matrix of size 1*300 and wish to get one sentence encoding (possibly 1*300) using all the words in the sentences. I am trying to use bi-directional LSTM using Keras
Is there a good solution for it?
Is there another way we should go about it?

Comment: i think you want a doc2vec model. try gensim or fasttext. keras does not have that without building it yourself